# ¿Cómo contabilizar los días entre dos fechas de distinto mes en caso de querer separarlos por meses en MariaDB?

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente tabla llamada *vacaciones*, donde se muestra el número de empleado junto con la fecha inicial y final de sus vacaciones:

| num_empleado | inicial | final |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 31/08/21 | 02/09/21 |
| 1002 | 01/09/21 | 04/09/21 |

Lo que busco es visualizar la cantidad de días de vacaciones que tuvo cada empleado, pero separándolos por mes.

Por ejemplo, si quisiera visualizar las vacaciones del empleado **1001**, se debería desplegar lo siguiente:

| dias | mes |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 9 |

Y en el caso del empleado **1002**, se debería desplegar de la siguiente manera:

| dias | mes |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 9 |

Tengo la siguiente *query* con la que he trabajado:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(final,inicial)+1 AS dias, MONTH(inicial) AS mes FROM vacaciones 
WHERE (MONTH(inicial) OR MONTH(final) = 8) AND (YEAR(inicial) 
AND YEAR(final) = 2021) AND num_empleado = 1001 GROUP BY dias
```

La cuestión es que, por ejemplo, con el empleado **1002** funciona perfecto, pero con el empleado **1001** no se despliega nada, ya que el rango de días en los que tomó las vacaciones está entre dos meses distintos.

¿Cómo podría adaptar mi *query* para considerar los rangos de días que pertenecen a diferente mes? Estoy usando MariaDB 10.4 en phpMyAdmin. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal es como a partir de dos fechas, sabemos cuantos días corresponden a cada mes. Una forma bastante robusta es "generar" los días entre los intervalos para luego contar los días por mes.

La generación dinámica de los días puede hacerse muy fácilmente si dispones de [`sequence engine`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/):

```
select v.num_empleado,
       DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) as Fecha
       from vacaciones v
       cross join seq_1_to_100 s
       where  DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.final
       order by v.num_empleado, , v.inicial, s.seq

num_empleado    Fecha
1001            2021-08-31
1001            2021-09-01
1001            2021-09-02
1002            2021-09-01
1002            2021-09-02
1002            2021-09-03
1002            2021-09-04
```

En este caso: `seq_1_to_100` generamos una secuencia hasta 100, el numero lo definirás en función de la cantidad máxima de días de vacaciones. Mediante el `cross join` o producto cartesiano generamos los días de vacaciones para cada empleado. Teniendo esta tabla es trivial agrupar por empleado y mes:

```
select num_empleado,
       EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha ) as YearMonth,
       count(1)                           as Dias
       from (select v.num_empleado,
                    DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) as Fecha
                    from vacaciones v
                    cross join seq_1_to_100 s
                       where  DATE_ADD(v.inicial, interval s.seq - 1 DAY) <= v.final
                    order by v.num_empleado, , v.inicial, s.seq
        ) t
        group by num_empleado,
                 EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha )


num_empleado    YearMonth   Dias
1001            202108      1
1001            202109      2
1002            202109      4
```

Comment: Por alguna razón tu *query* me genera valores que sobrepasan el número de días por mes. Cabe destacar que pueden haber múltiples registros por mes, por ejemplo: un registro que indica que se tomó un día de vacaciones el "2021/06/01", y posteriormente tomó cinco días en el mismo mes, del "2021-06-20" al "2021-06-25". No sé si ese planteamiento estaba en consideración, pero quiero creer que es parte de la razón por la cual suceden el tipo de resultado que expuse en un principio (filas que dan como resultado en la columna **dias** valores mayores al 31 en un mes).

Comment: @JorgeDuran, si absolutamente puede ser eso ¿`vacaciones` tiene algún id único que se pueda usar?

Comment: Así es, cada registro de la tabla **vacaciones** tiene su identificador. No lo planteé en la pregunta porque no creí que fuera necesario para realizar lo que se desea obtener.

Comment: En realidad, si los rangos no se cruzan, en teoría no haría falta. Fijate mi última edición a ver si resuelve el problema, sino te voy a pedir un ejemplo de los datos que generan el problema.

Comment: Sigue sucediendo lo mismo. Por ejemplo, tengo un de enero del 2021 para el empleado 2765, que dice que tomó vacaciones con fecha inicial de 2021-01-04 y fecha final de 2021-01-11. Es el único registro que tiene de ese mes. Otro detalle es que el mismo empleado tiene registros de los días de vacaciones que tomó durante meses y años anteriores.

Comment: No logro reproducir lo que comentas, cualquier cosa esta es mi prueba de concepto: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=226f29a5f8d0c35378238dc3046aced6

Comment: Una disculpa, revisando con detenimiento he visto que estás en lo correcto y el error fue mío. Tu respuesta es óptima y de hecho la mejor que he visto comparada con otras *queries* que investigué. Me parece que eres la mejor respuesta. Una última pregunta añadida (en caso de que haya forma): ¿Es posible separar el mes y año con su respectiva columna? Por cierto, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Si claro, simplemente reemplaza `EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM t.Fecha )` por `EXTRACT( YEAR FROM t.Fecha ), EXTRACT( MONTH FROM t.Fecha )`

Answer (score 0):

Acá mi solución (modificado para usar sintaxis de MariaDB)

```
With vacaciones_mensual as (
    SELECT num_empleado, 
           inicial, 
           CAST(DATE_FORMAT(inicial, '%Y-%m-01') AS DATETIME) mes
    from vacaciones
    union distinct
    SELECT num_empleado, 
           inicial, 
           CAST(DATE_FORMAT(inicial, '%Y-%m-01') AS DATETIME) mes
    from vacaciones
)
SELECT  num_empleado,
        inicial,
        final,
        CASE WHEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(inicial, '%Y-%m-01') = CAST(DATE_FORMAT(final, '%Y-%m-01')
            THEN DATEDIFF(final,inicial)
            WHEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(inicial, '%Y-%m-01') AS DATETIME) = mes
            then DATEDIFF(last_day(mes),inicial)+1
            ELSE DATEDIFF(final,mes)+1
        END AS dias, 
        MONTH(mes) AS mes 
FROM vacaciones a
JOIN vacaciones_mensual b
    ON a.num_empleado = b.num_empleado
        AND a.inicial = b.inicial
```

Y la explicación, por partes:

### 1. El `WITH` (CTE)

```
SELECT num_empleado, inicial, trunc(inicial, 'MM') mes
from vacaciones
union distinct
SELECT num_empleado, inicial, trunc(final, 'MM') mes
from vacaciones
```

Sacamos, para cada empleado y la fecha inicio de sus vacaciones (imagino que van a tener más de una), para luego por ejemplo si tenemos unas vacaciones en agosto y setiembre, tenemos un registro para agosto y otro para setiembre, lo llamaría un mes "auxiliar".

### 2. La suma de los días

```
CASE WHEN CAST(DATE_FORMAT(inicial, '%Y-%m-01') = CAST(DATE_FORMAT(final, '%Y-%m-01')
            THEN DATEDIFF(final,inicial) 
    WHEN trunc(inicial, 'MM') = mes
    then DATEDIFF(last_day(mes),inicial)+1
    ELSE DATEDIFF(final,mes)+1
END AS dias,
```

Lo que hace este bloque de código es, primero, si el mes inicial y el mes final son lo mismo, hace la diferencia de fechas normal (la correcta). De lo contrario, si el mes auxiliar es el mismo que el inicial, por ejemplo, en tu ejemplo para 31/08/21, el mes auxiliar sería 01/08/21 (agosto), por lo que vamos a sacar la cantidad de días en este mes (comparo datediff del último día de agosto (31) vs tu fecha `inicial` (31) + 1).
Luego hace lo mismo con setiembre, pero cuenta desde el principio del mes auxiliar (1/09) hasta el día del final de las vacaciones (4/09), con lo que deberías tener lo que pides :)

### Limitaciones

Es posible que si tienes vacaciones que ocupen más de dos meses no carguen correctamente (el mes del medio no se va a contar). Imagino que en el mundo real esto no ocurriría, pero en caso de que sí, creo que lo que deberías hacer es crear una tabla autogenerada  de meses "auxiliares" y hacerlo con un `JOIN xxx ON mes_auxiliar between inicial and final`, y bueno en el CASE tendrías que poner otro when (donde el mes auxiliar no sea ni el inicial, ni el final, cuentas los días del mes. Eso podrías sacarlo haciendo day(last_day(mes_auxiliar)).

Comment: Es una excelente respuesta, muchísimas gracias. Desgraciadamente olvidé especificar que estoy usando MariaDB 10.4 en phpMyAdmin, el cual parece ser incompatible con MySQL 8 (el cual incluye **WITH [CTE]**). Intenté reemplazar **WITH** con **CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE**, pero no obtuve el resultado esperado. ¿Alguna sugerencia? De igual forma aceptaré tu respuesta porque finalmente parece ser una respuesta correcta y quien falló en no especificar herramientas fui yo. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Ah ok, decía MySQL por los tags de la pregunta. Según veo la documentación, las CTE fueron añadidas en MariaDB 10.2.1, no podrías intentarlo? Sino, puedes probar con un ```CREATE TABLE AS``` y luego poner el select inicial?

Comment: De hecho investigando un poco, los CTE sí los acepta MariaDB, pero tiene bugs de paginación (tarda mucho al generar la consulta). Más información aquí: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/sql-parser/issues/165 Independientemente de eso, al hacer la consulta que recientemente editaste para MariaDB (cambiando **CONCAT()** por **CAST()**) me lanza números negativos en la columna **dias**. Las demás columnas están correctas, pero la columna de **dias**  me lanza números negativos o ceros que no concuerdan con la brecha de días. Por ejemplo, en un rango de dos días me lanza un "-18" o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Incluso cuando busqué alternativas para **WHERE** (que existen varias), curiosamente me sucedía lo mismo, entonces probablemente sea error del query.

Comment: Tienes razón! Me faltó poner el ```last_day(mes)``` en el CASE. A lo mejor funciona ahora (le había puesto solo mes, por lo que compararía el día 1 del mes con la fecha de las vacaciones, lo cual haría la diferencia negativa). Además no contemplaba cuando las vacaciones son en el mismo mes (por eso le añadí ```datediff(final,inicial)```)